# Force excel hyperlink to open Acrobat Reader without changing system default pdf reader

Tags: excel, windows, pdf, hyperlink, acrobat

Since many users may have different PDF editing/reviewing programs, but all users have Acrobat reader because of an IT policy, I want an excel hyperlink to open a PDF url using Acrobat reader.

I have yet to find this, but is there some url prefix alternative to `file://...` to something like `acrobat://...` ?

The PDF file is on the local network, not internet.

The reason for wanting Acrobat so I can use PDF open parameters:
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: Do you want to open a pdf file with adobe reader from excel from your computer (local drives)?

Comment: @harun24hr Yes, a local network drive

Answer (score 0):

Following sub will open a PDF file from local drive.

```
Sub OpenPDFbyAdobeReader()
    Dim OpenFile
    OpenFile = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe E:\TestFolder\TestFile.pdf", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

You may need to change the path of of adobe acrobat reader where it is installed in your PC. Replace the file path with you network path. I do not test it using network path. But the code is tested in my PC using local drive file path.

## ***Edit:***

The following code works for network path.

```
Sub OpenPDFbyAdobeReader()
    Dim OpenFile
    OpenFile = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe \\MyDesktop-PC\Share_Folder\Test_File.pdf", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

`\\MyDesktop-PC\Share_Folder\Test_File.pdf` is a file located on network path. You have ensure access permission to that file.

Comment: Can you use file open parameters, for example `#page-3`? Also, this works, but I receive an "access denied" when opening my PDF, but I can manually open my PDF from reader.